# Query editing apk name

Tags: apk

Will it effect working of app if I change name of apk using apk editor?
It's an VPN app and I want to change apk package name.
I'm not the owner of the apk and using apk editor app to modify the name.

Comment: Some apps contain an "repackaging protection" which will detect name changes and/or resigning and then quit/kill the app.

Comment: thanks for your answer Robert, but the app runs fine without crash.Asking about background process of data collection by app as the app is related to research.

Comment: An app that does not crashes necessarily means it runs correctly. If you want to make sure everything is working perform tests, collect the `logcat` output and scan for Exceptions and decompile the app to understand what it does. Anyway I still not understand why you want to change the package name of an VPN app.